# Salvando dados com relacionamento hasMany

Tags: laravel

Estou tentando fazer um update e três tabelas relacionadas com o Laravel, os dados passados vem de uma unica view, e os relacionamentos já foram feitos, deve ser a action update do meu controller que não está certa segue abaixo.

Update do `CorretoresControllers`

```
public function update(Corretor $corretor, Request $request) {
    $corretor->update($request->all());
    return redirect('corretores');
}
```

Model `Corretor`

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Endereco;
use App\Contato;
use App\Documento;

class Corretor extends Model {

    protected $fillable = ['nome', 'email'];
    protected $table = 'corretors';

    public function endereco() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Endereco');
    }

    public function contato() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Contato');
    }

    public function documento(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Documento');
    }
}
```

Quando do um `dd($request->all());` me retorna os seguintes dados:

```
array:11 [▼
  "_method" => "PUT"
  "_token" => "sWlp1StEgwx7PXZbjo7nV8eYecKpic32E21YeWxA"
  "nome" => "Bruno Neves 1"
  "email" => "brunosantos170@gmail.com"
  "logradouro" => "TV DO PARAISO 214"
  "numero" => "10"
  "telefone" => "9632242778"
  "celular1" => "9999-9999"
  "celular2" => "9999-9999"
  "cpf" => "123"
  "rg" => "123"
]
```

Já quado do um `dd($corretor);` me retorna somente esses dados:

```
"id" => "13"
    "nome" => "Bruno Santos"
    "email" => "brunosantos170@gmail.com"
    "created_at" => "2016-01-26 00:55:11"
    "updated_at" => "2016-02-04 03:14:27"
```

Comment: Ai Bruno a resposta do companheiro resolveu seu problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sempre que for salvar dados no `Laravel` você precisa definir no model os campos que são "preenchíveis", no caso em `$fillable`.

Adicione os campos da tabela que você deseja adicionar em `$fillable`. Eu também sempre que altero a tabela e coloco um novo campo esqueço de alterar o valor dessa propriedade.

## Salvando dados em relacionamentos

Se você pretende salvar os dados de relacionamento, é necessário especificar isso, pois isso não é feito automaticamente.

Para salvar dados de um relacionamento `hasMany` é necessário usar o método `saveMany`.

```
$documentos = [
   new App\Documento($dadosDocumento)
];

$enderecos = [
   new App\Endereco($dadosEndereco),
];

$contato->fill($dadosContato)->save();

$contato->documentos()->saveMany($documentos);

$contato->enderecos()->saveMany($enderecos);
```

Separei os dados em variáveis diferentes, como `$dadosEndereco` e `$dadosContato`. Geralmente uso o método `only`. Pode ser feito simplesmente assim:

```
$dadosEndereco = $request->only(['logradouro', 'numero'])
```

O resultado será:

```
['logradouro' => 'Rua T', 'numero' => 116]
```

Comment: Em minhas todas as minhas models existe a varialvel $fillable com os respectivos campos da tabela, segui sua dica e o metodo update do controller ficou assim:

public function update(Corretor $corretor, Request $request) {

        $documentos = [ new App\Documento($dadosDocumento) ];
        $enderecos  = [ new App\Endereco($dadosEndereco) ];

        $corretor->documentos()->saveMany($documentos);
        $corretor->enderecos()->saveMany($enderecos);


        return redirect('corretores');
    }
Está certo ? testei e da o seguinte erro:

Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App\Documento' not found

Comment: Nem todo código postado aqui precisa ser real. A ideia do código postado não era aplicar um CTRL+C e CTRL+V, mas sim tirar uma base para resolver o seu problema específico. Afinal, eu estou vendo apenas trecho do código, e o seu script pode possuir outras dependências.